# Cloudfare - Stunnel - SSL error of NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID - Windows 10 pro

Tags: ssl

I can get in just deep enough water to get into trouble these days.

I had this running with a Let'sEncrypt and got sick of redoing it every 3 months so I wanted a longer cert expiration. In came CloudFare with a 15 year cert, essentially a one and done.

I have DNS pointed to CF and propagated. I have CF setup on Full (strict) and had it issue an origin cert for my domain.

I imported the main CF cert into the server, the authority cert, under trusted and intermediary. I thought this would fix it but nope.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Here is the error from Stunnel:
2021.08.24 19:34:54 LOG3[5]: SSL_accept: ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Comment: When I look at the cert here by clicking on the lock and going to view Cert it says issued to *stackexchange.com

Mine shows issued to cloudfare.com

This seems like the issue as it isn't serving MY cert but instead serving cloudfares cert.